# Making Outbound Calls

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Anybody know if it's possible to make a blackberry app that can perform outbound calls? Specifically, would it be possible to have a loop within an app that redials a number until somebody answers (eg. call in to a radio station until you get an answer).

Answer (score 4):

Yes [this is possible](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Make_call_723711_11.jsp).

[Another method](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Start_phone_app_fromBB_device_app_565541_11.jsp).

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas if we can check whether the call was answered, ended, etc?

Comment: @Rob You should check the [PhoneListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneListener.html) and the [AbstractPhoneListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/AbstractPhoneListener.html) classes if you want to know whether the call was answered, ended and etc.